# MeCab: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, mecab

This is the first time to use python.

I installed MeCab through "mecab_python_windows-0.9.9.6-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl"

Then I used this

```
import MeCab
test = "今日はいい天気ですね。遊びに行かない？新宿で祭りがある！"
mt = MeCab.Tagger("-d C:\Program Files (x86)\MeCab\dic\ipadic")
print(mt.parse(test))
```

and got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/mecab/main.py", line 1, in <module>
   import MeCab
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\MeCab.py", line 21, in <module>
   _MeCab = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\MeCab.py", line 20, in 
    swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_MeCab')
  File "D:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Akira! I see that you installed `ipadic` but did you install MeCab ([website](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#win))? I.e., can you `mecab` in the Windows command line and parse some text? (The Python module needs MeCab installed to work.)

Answer (score 1):

First,you should install mecab-0.996.exe.
Second,copy this file "E:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Python36\Lib\site-packages\libmecab.dll"
to "C:\Windows\System32"
or
copy this file "E:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\Python36\Lib\site-packages\libmecab.dll"
to "E:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages"

Then it will be OK!
[image]